# Tracking more events to Mixpanel using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, mixpanel

I have some events tracked to Mixpanel. Now I want to send a few more events doing an Ajax call, so I create a new `<script>` tag dynamically with the Mixpanel code (again) and the new event/s:

```
var newKissmetrics = '{% render "ProMixpanelBundle:Default:JSCodeAjax" %}; '
+ ' mixpanel.track("Searched By Coordinates", {"result": "with results", "searched": "otherValue"})';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = newKissmetrics;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

The `<script>` tag dynamically loaded becomes:

`<script>
<!-- start Mixpanel -->(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" "); for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]); mixpanel.init("here goes the token");<!-- end Mixpanel -->mixpanel.set_config({"debug":true}); mixpanel.track("Searched Community By Coordinates", {"result": "with results", "searched": "otherValue"})
</script>`

So seems to be right... but Mixpanel is not tracking this new event. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is too obvious. I was repeating the snipped code, already sent to the browser with the standard call (before the Ajax call). This works:

```
 var newKissmetrics = 'mixpanel.track("Searched By Coordinates", {"result": "with results", "searched": "otherValue"})';
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.innerHTML = newKissmetrics;
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```